# K8s nodeLocalDns pod times out connecting to coreDns after upgrading base os to ubuntu20.04 ConnectX-4 card

Tags: kubernetes, ubuntu-18.04, ubuntu-20.04, calico, mellanox

Team,

I have Mellanox Nic ConnectX-4 on a k8s worker node and it hosts a nodeLocal dns pod on it. The nodeLocalDns pod is timing out when trying to connect to coreDns service on k8s cluster.

Same works on Ubuntu18.

Versions failing with

```
k8s v1.13.5 Baremetal
Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS   
kernel 5.4.0-100-generic   
docker://19.3.13
```

below works well.

```
 k8s v1.13.5 Baremetal
 Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS   
 kernel  4.15.0-45-generic   
 docker://18.9.2
```

Any hint how can I debug this? I am getting no clue in logs.

Errors are from nodeLocalDNS pod logs.

```
A: dial tcp 100.60.3.4:53: i/o timeout
```

Where above is coreDns service and it is pingable from nodeLocalDns pod but not connecting on dns port.

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use and how did you set up the cluster? Did you use bare metal installation or some cloud provider?

Comment: added in description `Baremetal k8s 1.13.5`

Answer (score 0):

It was a interoperability issue that we fixed disabling checksum off on the NIC of the node. after below command, pod networking started working. this was only with mellanix ConnectX-4. same was not observed with ConnectX-5

```
ethtool -K ens1 rx on tx off
```